# Loop always return the last image

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, swift3, scenekit

I'm trying to add a different scnMaterial(UIImage) on each geometry with a loop, but the loop is not working. The loop always return the last image. So I always see the same last image on every geometry.

```
  class GameScene: SCNScene {

    var geometry = SCNBox()
    var boxnode = SCNNode()

    convenience init(create: Bool) {
        self.init()

        let offset: Int = 10
        var matCounter:Int = 1
        for xIndex:Int in 0...1 {
            for yIndex:Int in 0...1 {
                // create a geometry copy
                let geometry = SCNBox(width: 0.8 , height: 0.8, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0.005)
                let geometry1 = SCNBox(width:2 , height: 2, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0.005)

                let img = UIImage(named:"\(matCounter).png")
                let material = SCNMaterial()
                material.diffuse.contents = img
                geometry1.firstMaterial = material
                geometry1.firstMaterial = material
                matCounter = matCounter + 1

                let boxnode = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
                boxnode.position.x = Float(xIndex - offset)
                boxnode.position.y = Float(yIndex - offset)

                let geometry1Node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry1)
                geometry1Node.position.x = Float(xIndex - 20)
                geometry1Node.position.y = Float(yIndex - 20)

                self.rootNode.addChildNode(boxnode)
                self.rootNode.addChildNode(geometry1Node)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the result that I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: which line are you returning something?

Comment: `geoCopy.firstMaterial = material` this line is always overwriting the `firstMaterial` property. Only the last value set would persist.

Comment: Please update your question explaining how do you decide which material to apply to which geometry. I am guessing here: should every `nth` node in your grid, apply a material whose name is `<<n>>.png`?

Comment: @dmsurti no every geometry should have their own different image. That's my problem, I don't know how to apply a different material to each geometry.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I know what the problem is. I just can't find a solution.

Comment: Guys I just want 6 geometry with six different material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I just want 6 geometry with six different material

and assuming that you are

1. rendering 6 geometries, with different dimensions, within your nested for loop and
2. have six images named 1.png to 6.png in your app bundle;

you could do this:

```
override init()
{
    super.init()

    typealias BoxDims = (width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat,
                         length: CGFloat, chamferRadius: CGFloat)

    let box1Dim = BoxDims(CGFloat(0.8), CGFloat(0.8), CGFloat(0.10), CGFloat(0.005))
    let box2Dim = BoxDims(CGFloat(0.7), CGFloat(0.7), CGFloat(0.15), CGFloat(0.006))
    let box3Dim = BoxDims(CGFloat(0.9), CGFloat(0.6), CGFloat(0.12), CGFloat(0.007))
    let box4Dim = BoxDims(CGFloat(1.2), CGFloat(0.9), CGFloat(0.18), CGFloat(0.003))
    let box5Dim = BoxDims(CGFloat(1.0), CGFloat(1.0), CGFloat(0.11), CGFloat(0.008))
    let box6Dim = BoxDims(CGFloat(1.1), CGFloat(1.1), CGFloat(0.16), CGFloat(0.009))

    let allBoxDims = [box1Dim, box2Dim, box3Dim, box4Dim, box5Dim, box6Dim]

    let offset: Int = 10
    var boxCounter: Int = 0
    for xIndex: Int in 0...2
    {
        for yIndex: Int in 0...1
        {
            // create a geometry
            let boxDim = allBoxDims[boxCounter]
            let geo = SCNBox(width: boxDim.width, height: boxDim.height,
                             length: boxDim.length,
                             chamferRadius: boxDim.chamferRadius)

            let img = UIImage(named: "\(boxCounter + 1).png")
            let material = SCNMaterial()
            material.diffuse.contents = img
            geo.firstMaterial = material
            boxCounter = boxCounter + 1

            let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: geo)
            boxNode.position.x = Float(xIndex - offset)
            boxNode.position.y = Float(yIndex - offset)
            self.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
        }
    }
}
```

You need to have *some logic* which you translate into code, to apply the material to a geometry. If you don't have any rule/logic, then you can just apply randomly.

Comment: Thanks again @dmsurti, if I want each geometry to have different sizes, can it be done with a copy? Thanks

Comment: Assuming you just want to use the same geometry but scaled up, you can set `boxNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(2, 2, 2)` which will double the geometry size in all `x, y, z` axis. If they are different geometry, you set each node with a different geometry object.

Comment: The first suggestion will not work and I do not totally understand the second suggestion(If you could give an example I would really appreciate it). I want a grid with SCNbox of different sizes (15 box). I want to set the sizes myself. I've never try SCNKit before so It's a little hard for me to understand. Thanks

Comment: If you want 15 boxes with different sizes, then you need to create 15 geometries, one for each box. So you won't create a geometry copy. Instead  you do: `let geometry =SCNBox(width: w , height: h, length: l, chamferRadius: cr)` instead of `let geoCopy = ...` in the nested for loop., where you set w, h, l, cr for each box.

Comment: I just updated my question, to show you the result. Could you check it out please.

Comment: Why are you creating 2 geometries/2 nodes in the for loop? Every loop executions should create one box node with geometry and material. So for every for loop execution, your geometry parameters should change so that each box will get a different geometry. `let geometry = SCNBox(width: 0.8 , height: 0.8, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0.005)
                let geometry1 = SCNBox(width:2 , height: 2, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0.005)` is wrong. There should be only `let geometry = ...` in that for loop as I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @John Updated answer to show `one possible` way of having boxes with different dimensions. Just like material, you need to have `some logic` to decide which box has what dimensions.

Comment: Thanks @dmsurti , I will ask a new question about how to load images to the nodes from firebase. I will paste the link here, Will you be able to help me if I post it?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412523/scnnode-and-firebase?noredirect=1#comment70069921_41412523

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 1...5 {
    if let img = UIImage(named: "\(i)"){
         images.append(img)
         let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = img
        geoCopy.firstMaterial = material

    }
 }
```

This will always leave `geoCopy.firstMaterial` Initialized from Image 5, if it exists.